# Mergeadapter memory leaking?

Tags: android, memory-leaks

I am investigating a outofmemoryerror bugreport in our app.

Our app shows a listview with application icons as part of a listview item.

When this listview is populated using a standard baseadapter, it is observed that the app doesn't hold on to the drawables when the views that contain them go out of sight.

This is also tested with a weakreference:

```
 public Drawable getIcon() {
        Log.v("AppResult", "getIcon()");
        Drawable icon = appInfo.loadIcon(pm);       
        leakTester.add(new WeakReference<Drawable>(icon));
        ArrayList<WeakReference<Drawable>> copy = new ArrayList<WeakReference<Drawable>>(leakTester); 
        for (WeakReference<Drawable> oldIcon: leakTester)
        {
            if (oldIcon.get() == null)
            {
                Log.v("AppResult", "iconRecycled");
                copy.remove(oldIcon);
            }
        }
        leakTester = copy;
        return icon;
    }
```

Log when scrolling through the normal baseadapter powered listview:

```
12-05 16:17:57.450: V/AppResult(24890): getIcon()
12-05 16:17:57.450: V/AppResult(24890): iconRecycled
12-05 16:17:57.510: V/AppResult(24890): getIcon()
12-05 16:17:57.520: V/AppResult(24890): iconRecycled
12-05 16:17:57.580: V/AppResult(24890): getIcon()
12-05 16:17:57.590: V/AppResult(24890): iconRecycled
12-05 16:17:57.730: V/AppResult(24890): getIcon()
12-05 16:17:57.730: V/AppResult(24890): iconRecycled
12-05 16:17:58.510: V/AppResult(24890): getIcon()
12-05 16:17:58.510: V/AppResult(24890): iconRecycled
12-05 16:17:58.570: V/AppResult(24890): getIcon()
12-05 16:17:58.570: V/AppResult(24890): iconRecycled
12-05 16:17:58.650: V/AppResult(24890): getIcon()
```

However, when I use a mergeAdapter, that is filled with alternating header textviews and baseadapters like the one earlier used, I get very few  `iconRecycled` messages. Even though these adapters do use a recycleview when available. (The app goes to a 35MB usage! after scrolling through the full list, while it stays at 12MB in the other activity).

```
12-05 16:15:04.800: V/AppResult(24890): getIcon()
12-05 16:15:04.860: D/dalvikvm(24890): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 34K, 1% free 35857K/36167K, paused 26ms
12-05 16:15:04.860: V/AppResult(24890): getIcon()
12-05 16:15:04.910: V/AppResult(24890): getIcon()
12-05 16:15:04.910: V/AppResult(24890): getIcon()
12-05 16:15:04.910: V/AppResult(24890): iconRecycled
12-05 16:15:04.910: V/AppResult(24890): iconRecycled
12-05 16:15:04.950: V/AppResult(24890): getIcon()
12-05 16:15:04.950: V/AppResult(24890): getIcon()
12-05 16:15:04.950: V/AppResult(24890): getIcon()
12-05 16:15:13.260: V/AppResult(24890): getIcon()
12-05 16:15:13.430: V/AppResult(24890): getIcon()
12-05 16:15:13.590: V/AppResult(24890): getIcon()
12-05 16:15:14.300: V/AppResult(24890): getIcon()
12-05 16:15:14.370: V/AppResult(24890): getIcon()
12-05 16:15:14.440: V/AppResult(24890): getIcon()
```

Is this an error in my implementation? It looks like the mergeadapter somehow doesn't release the views that are not in view anymore. Is this correct?

EDIT

I ran it through MAT and this is the result:

```
java.util.ArrayList[32] @ 0x413beb88  144 19.833.288 
  \mScrapViews android.widget.AbsListView$RecycleBin @ 0x4129bd9040 19.833.496 
    .\mRecycler android.widget.ListView @ 0x412c5db8  896 23.635.384 
      ..+mFocusedView, mRealFocusedView android.view.ViewRootImpl @ 0x4133fae8 440 1.776 
        ..|+this$0 android.view.ViewRootImpl$2 @ 0x4136f540 Native Stack 16 16 
        ..|+[1] android.view.ViewRootImpl[2] @ 0x41340930 » 24 24 
        ..|+this$0 android.view.ViewRootImpl$AccessibilityInteractionConnectionManager @ 0x413157e8 » 16 16 
        ..|\Total: 3 entries       
      ..+mServedView, mNextServedView android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager @ 0x413511f8 » 104 368 
      ..+listview com.denper.addonsdetector.ui.InstallDateLister @ 0x412d8bd8 »
```

Answer (score 0):

> It looks like the mergeadapter somehow doesn't release the views that are not in view anymore. Is this correct?

If by "the views" you mean the "alternating header textviews", then of course `MergeAdapter` "doesn't release the views that are not in view anymore" -- if `MergeAdapter` released them, then `MergeAdapter` cannot display them when the user scrolls back, because it has no way to get those `View`s back again once released.

If by "the views" you mean the contents of "baseadapters like the one earlier used", then `MergeAdapter` never holds those `View`s in the first place, and therefore cannot be holding them. However, it is possible that the increased values for methods like `getCount()` will cause caching changes in `ListView`.

Comment: Hi, yes I am talking about the baseadapters. Somehow this is causing caching issues as you see. So, I don't really get why this is happening, and you also not as I understand?

Comment: @Peterdk: I certainly am not aware of any problems in this area, or how `MergeAdapter` could be at fault. You may wish to use MAT to confirm exactly who is holding onto what.

Comment: I ran it through MAT (see updated question), and it shows that the listview is keeping all the views in it's recyclebin. According to some other info the internet that is the place where it keeps all the views that are shown. They only get removed when given as convertview. However I do use a convertview. It is due the mergeadapter that the multiple baseadapters do not get the recycled views from the other adapters that are equal. So it's definitely not a good idea to use for headers between view lists.

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with me not implementing getviewtype? Then it would not be a mergeadapter bug, will try that.

Comment: Yes, as it looks now it is due to the mergeadapter overriding `getItemViewType` with a custom implementation and therefor not returning recycled views to baseadapters that share the same view layout and thus could be recycled.

Comment: @Peterdk: I have no way to know that the other adapters "share the same view layout and thus could be recycled", so `MergeAdapter` takes a conservative approach. You are welcome to extend `MergeAdapter` and override `getViewTypeCount()` and `getItemViewType()` to reflect knowledge that you have about the adapters you are putting into your `MergeAdapter`.

Comment: Ok, great. I handcoded it to two viewtypes and added a check to see from which adapter they come and now it works as expected!

Comment: @Peterdk I am facing the same problem i am using mergeadapter  and Using MAT i notice that Receyclebin in ABSListView is taking alot of memory . I am using MergeADapter to add 5 different adapters and each adapter has 1-2 different row views. I am using the ViewHolder pattern to reuse convertview . how did you manage to solve your problem

Comment: here is my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20529373/heap-grows-with-out-of-memory-exception-using-mergeadapter-in-android

Comment: @user4o01 see the last comment of Commonsware. You need to override these 2 methods to let the listview know that items are the same viewtype, so they can be recycled.

Comment: override them in mergeadapter right since i overrode them in my baseadapter's ?