# Heap Grows with Out Of Memory Exception using MergeAdapter in android

Tags: java, android, memory

I have an android application that contains 3 Activities . each one contains one Fragment and each fragment fires 3-7 `loaders` to load data from Server and display them in `ListView` using **MegeAdapter** by commonsware. Any way while using the app on Nexus 4 (android 4.4) i got an out of memory exception .

I played around the MAT tool but the Big object reside in (reminder) area which is not selectable . I can't view them .

Note:

> In developer option if i check don't keep activies and make the
> Background process limit to "No background process" then the heap size
> remains between 10.500 MB to 12.00 MB (using the Update heap in DDMS).

What should i do to make the same effect so i keep the heap size nice like this ?

I can't find leaks in my application !!

also note :
I don't have any service component running in the application .
i have set largeHeap="true"

UPDATE : FROM MAT I GOT YOU SOME SCREEN SHOTS
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you perhaps upload the full hprof, so we can have a look?